# Loading pre-set script in with a String

Tags: java, android, eclipse, command-line, command

Ok I have not done a very good job explaining my problem so here goes revised a few times.

I have a Survey, The Survey Produces an Integer Number. I Convert this Number into a String File name Which relates to a Preset String stored in my resources. Based on the choices made on the questions a different string is required at the end.

This code generates the desired command line; R.string.c####

```
    int Q1 = question1.getmCounter();
int Q2 = question2.getmCounter();
int Q3 = question3.getmCounter();
int Q4 = question4.getmCounter();

int qTotal = Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4;
String Test5 = "R.string.c" + qTotal;
```

And This code is inside onCreate to generate the content for the TextView.

```
        textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ChmpNametxt);
    textOut.setText(Test5);
```

Now my concept was that it would read Test5 as "R.string.c####" and load the desired string. It does not do this and i would like to know how i can get the contents of Test5 into a commandline.

Hope someon can help me im malting..

Thanks in Advance

-Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the correct answer here already: [Creating Strings than can be used as Filepath - Eclipse / Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489432/creating-strings-than-can-be-used-as-filepath-eclipse-andriod)

In your case:

```
String stringId = "c" + qTotal; //note: not the same as what you did with your Test5
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(stringId, "string", getPackageName());
textOut.setText(resId);
```

Or are we misunderstandig your use of the word "commandline"?

Comment: Aha I see what's going on now..It doesn't like getPackageName though, do i need to declare something in there?

Comment: ah don't use getClass(), remove that part, updated the answer

Comment: It worked, your a life saver man, i nearly died from lack of sleep!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the reosurce id for your text, this code gets the resource id for you:

```
ContextWrapper cw = this.getContext();// how you get this can be different, but you need a ContextWrapper from somewhere to use.
int resId = cw.getResources().getIdentifier("c" + qTotal, "string", cw.getPackageName());
```

Then you can use textOut.setText with the resId variable as the parameter.

Comment: Nor after your edit, looks like you pasted my first version of the code that forgot the "" around the c :)

Comment: @Pulsar yes, just realized that when I saw your answer. Edited.

Comment: I'm clearly missing some obvious piece of logic here.. i cant seem to get it to work. Maybe because im mostly asleep.
@Pulsar I am having problems with the .getPackageName in your answer and Simon André Forsberg I'm having problems with the context in yours xD

I feel clueless, thanks for your effort though guys :)